# Как правильно подобрать регулярное выражение?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста правильно подобрать регулярное выражение.

Условие выражения следующие - в него должны попадать любые символы кроме `html` тегов.

Вот я что-то похожее набросал, но оно отрабатывает недостаточно точно (может куски ссылок, если в тексте присутствуют, пропустить к примеру)

```
[^<a-zA-Z/>\:=\".;]+
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, поправить.

Comment: а что считать "тегом"? если все, что между угловыми кавычками, то так и писать: открывающая угловая кавычка + все кроме закрывающей угловой кавычки + закрывающая угловая кавычка, т.е. `<[^>]+>`. Только так вы рискуете потерять сравнения вида `1 < 2 > 0`, см примеры [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/pK2qE2/2)

Comment: не, немного не так, в регулярку должно входить все кроме тегов, может можно ее как-то безболезненно инвертировать?
то есть <tar class="cl1" param param1>то, что вошло в регулярку</tag>

Answer (score 1):

в php для этого есть встроенные функции. регулярки тут лишние

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php

оно?

Comment: Неа( Мне то, что регулярка наработала надо в массив потом закинуть

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.